# Can i use XCUITest with swift for UI Automation for an iOS app which is developed using Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, automation, xcuitest

I am a beginner for XCUITest framework,

**My question is :**
Can i use XCUITest with Swift programming to automate an iOS app which is developed using Objective C or i need to use Objective C only?

Thanks,

mra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

`XCUITests` create separate application that runs in parallel with your main application. So it can be in any language.

And don't forget that `Swift` and `Objective-C` can be mixed in one project anyway.

Comment: Thank You!! for the clarification.